# Laravel Nova Auto-Refresh Resource

Tags: laravel-nova

According to the Laravel Nova Website the release 3.10.0 has this new features:

```
Added new "standalone" actions for running actions without selecting resources. #961
Added ability for resources to auto-refresh their index listing. #957
```

The links to the pull requests, of course, don't work because this is no open source project.

I can't find anything in the docs about this new features. How to use them?

Answer (score -1):

In your action class add the code below, to override the default value, set to false in /nova/src/Actions/Action.php.

```
/**
* Indicates if the action can be run without any models.
*
* @var bool
*/
public $standalone = true;
```

Comment: It's action, not resource. Also, `$standalone` is not for auto refresh